# windows.h no such file or directory (compile c code on linux)

Tags: c

I have a c program that includes a header . This program works fine on windows but on linux when I compile the code with:

```
gcc main.c -Wall -o main
```

I get:

> main.c:2:10: fatal error windows.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Do you have any idea why this error happens and how to fix?

Comment: You need to port the code to Linux

Comment: The problem is obvious: Linux, unlike Windows, does not have a `windows.h` header. Fixing it is more complex (you'll need to remove or replace any Windows-specific functionality), and impossible without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Code that is written to use `windows.h` will not easily run on Unix.  The Windows API is completely different from the Unix (Linux, POSIX) API.  You have to make major changes (function names, types, and so on) to get the code to work on Unix.  Or get a Windows-compatibility package that does provide `windows.h` — such things used to exist, but I've not used one in a decade or more.

Comment: Simple reason: Linux is not Windows.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: ugh, winelib/`winegcc` - AFAIK they still kinda work, but then you are better off using a cross-compiler + "regular" wine - `winegcc` "executables" still depend on wine, and winelib is a way less tested platform (I still have nightmares about the time I traced some crashes to the fact that in winegcc/winelib `std::wstring` was broken at ABI level).

Comment: @smack89: Rolled back. The tags are not justified, OP apparently can **not** use the WinAPI. And it is not specifically about compilation either.

Comment: @Olaf Where does OP say say he cannot use winapi? And what do you mean it is not about compilation?

Comment: @s: Getting a compiler error does not juistify [tag:compilation]. And OP apparently tries to compile some windows source code for Linux. So he does not use the winapi, but needs to use the "Linux" API (whatever that would be considering that the WinAPI covers various layers).

Comment: @Olaf, that literally makes no sense. "Getting a compiler error" is a result of trying to "Compile", hence "Compilation". `windows.h` contains the headers for the windows api, therefore if the OP was trying to compile a program which uses `windows.h`, he is still making use of windows api, so the question has something to do with the windows api; it might not be specified, what, but it's still there

Comment: @smac89: So you would add this tag to **every** question about a problem with compiling C code? May I recommend reading the info of this tag? Re. the other issue: OP tries to compile a C program code on **Linux**. There is no WinAPI on Linux. And there is no "windows.h" header. So it is not about the WinPI, but a simple problem with a missing header. There is not enough information in the question what OP actually wants to accomplish. But he definitively does not ask about the WinAPI!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that your code is using the windows.h header file to get function declarations for Windows-only functions. This file does not normally exist on Linux, because its installations of toolchains (such as GCC) will (by default) only include the files needed to compile for Linux.

You have a few options:

1. As Ed Heal [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111050/windows-h-no-such-file-or-directory-compile-c-code-on-linux#comment69426608_41111050), port the code to Linux. That means you would remove the inclusion of windows.h, and replace all the function calls that used the Windows API with their Linux equivalents. This will make your source code only work on Linux, unless you can refactor the OS-dependent calls into platform-agnostic code. A word of warning: unless the program you're working with is trivial, this is not an easy task. There's no guarantee that every Windows API function has a Linux equivalent.
2. Install a Windows toolchain for your build system, which should include windows.h, and [cross-compile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) your code. This will result in a binary that won't work on Linux, but *will* work on Windows.
3. A middle ground between those two options would be to actually do both, and use [conditional compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation) to allow you to selectively compile for one target or another.

Comment: About point (2): almost certainly the generated binary *can* work on Linux thanks to *wine* - actually, I often say half-jockingly that Win32 executables are the only binaries that you can reliably run unchanged on almost any Linux distribution. =)

Comment: @MatteoItalia You're right, but that's outside the scope of this question, so I left it out. OP is obviously new to this arena, so I wanted to avoid muddying the waters with Wine.

Comment: Any more details how to do the crosscompiling?

Comment: @M.Volf Googling "linux coss-compile for windows" will give you plenty of resources. It's been a while since I've had to do it, so any specific advice I could give is probably outdated. Taking a look at the mingw package is probably a good place to start.